# Spark job cancelled when execute take method at (string, List(string)) RDD tuple

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, rdd

My Spark job generate a Rdd tuple like (string, List(string)), when I save all datas, it runs ok, but it doesn't work when I save data with method take(100), some times it returns 100 key but no values. Can someone help me to solve this problem? Thx.
There is Spark error logs:

```
User class threw exception: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job 1 cancelled as part of cancellation of all jobs
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1515)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleJobCancellation(DAGScheduler.scala:1443)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$doCancelAllJobs$1.apply$mcVI$sp(DAGScheduler.scala:735)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$doCancelAllJobs$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:735)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$doCancelAllJobs$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:735)
at scala.collection.mutable.HashSet.foreach(HashSet.scala:78)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.doCancelAllJobs(DAGScheduler.scala:735)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onError(DAGScheduler.scala:1749)
at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:52)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:641)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1957)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1970)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1990)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1.apply$mcV$sp(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1154)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1095)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1095)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsHadoopDataset(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1095)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$4.apply$mcV$sp(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1069)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$4.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1035)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$4.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1035)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsHadoopFile(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1035)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$1.apply$mcV$sp(PairRDDFunctions.scala:961)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$1.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:961)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$1.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:961)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsHadoopFile(PairRDDFunctions.scala:960)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$saveAsTextFile$1.apply$mcV$sp(RDD.scala:1522)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$saveAsTextFile$1.apply(RDD.scala:1501)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$saveAsTextFile$1.apply(RDD.scala:1501)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.saveAsTextFile(RDD.scala:1501)
```

Comment: Hi Cisol, please share the code that generate this error.

Comment: itemRdd.map { item =>
                    val ids = item._2.map(x => x.substring(0, x.indexOf(":")))
                    (item._1, ids)
                }.take(100)
        sparkContext.makeRDD(itemRdd).repartition(1).saveAsTextFile("/test")

type of itemRdd is RDD[(string, string)], eg: [("23", "1:1,2:2,3:3")]